# How to set up a route that creates a new document and stores the new document inside an array field of another document

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to create an Inventory application. I want a situation where every Order(s) made on a particular product is stored in an Array on the ProductInventory document. I have a ProductInventory schema and Orders Schema.

```
// productInventory Schema

const ProductInventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({


   name : String,
   description : String, 
   price:Number,
   quantity :Number,
   supplier : String, 
   taxable : Boolean,
  orders: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Orders",
      required: true
    },


},{timestamps:true});



module.exports = mongoose.model('inventory', ProductInventorySchema)
```

```
// Order Schema

  const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({


      name : String,
      quantity: Number,,

   issuedBy : String,
   collectedBy: String,
   department : String,

},{timestamps:true});


module.exports = mongoose.model('order', OrderSchema)
```

My strategy is this: Attach each and every order made on a particular product to the ProductInventory, That way, I can do several things like calculating total orders qty and subtract from the ProductInventory qty, I can also query for all orders related to each ProductInventory.

My challenge is basically to write a code that creates a new order and then appends it to a chosen ProductInventory and finally stores it as an Array on the ProductInventory document.

I know I one of the best options is to make use of the Populate API from mongoose, but can't seem to figure out how to write the code for the required route

Comment: In the question, I'm having a confusion understanding. usually, product inventory is set of all products and order is basically, ordering something which is present in the inventory.
correct me, if I'm thinking in the way you want it to be?

Comment: @Saikat I'm basically trying to Populate the ProductInventory  with orders

Comment: Yes you are correct "product inventory is set of all products and order is basically, ordering something which is present in the inventory"

Comment: so for your schema, when doing `.find()` or `.findOne()` you can make you of `.populate('orders')`, before that make sure, the `ref` you added, that's matching with your model, in your case I guess it should be `order ` not `Orders `, let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProductInventorySchema` schema should be like this:

```
const ProductInventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name : String,
   description : String, 
   price:Number,
   quantity :Number,
   supplier : String, 
   taxable : Boolean,
   orders: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "orders",
      required: true
    }],
},{timestamps:true});
```

Example endpoint:

```
const Inventory = require('./productInventorySchema.js');
const Order = require('./orderSchema.js');

app.post('/order', async (req, res) => {
  const { name, quantity, issuedBy, collectedBy, department, inventoryId } = req.body;
  const order = await Order.create({
    name,
    quantity,
    issuedBy,
    collectedBy,
    department
  });

  const inventory = await Inventory.find({ _id: inventoryId });
  inventory.orders.push(order._id);
  await inventory.save();

  res.send('Order created');
});
```

The code above is not tested. It is just to give an idea of how you can achieve it. The code can be improved.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out and report the outcome

Comment: Got an error, the code really needs to be worked on